# Implicit conversion of lefthand argument in in-class declared friend operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, friend, crtp

I am using CRTP to provide template-argument dependent addition of functions to a class, in this case the addition of `operator +` and `operator +=`, using the template class `ImplAdd`. For the former, implicit conversions should be performed on both arguments, which means I have to use an in-class friend operator like this:

```
template<class Type, bool active>
struct ImplAdd{
    virtual int get_val_() const = 0;
    virtual void set_val_(int) = 0;
};

//if activated is true, the operators + and += will be defined
template<class Type>
class ImplAdd < Type, true > {
    virtual int get_val_() const = 0;
    virtual void set_val_(int) = 0;
    Type* this_(){ return (Type*)this; }
public:
    Type& operator +=(const Type& x){
        set_val_(get_val_() + x.get_val_());
        return *this_();
    }

    //This should enable conversions on the lefthand argument
    friend Type& operator+(const Type& lhs, const Type& rhs){
        Type ret = lhs;
        return ret += rhs;
    }
};
```

This is needed because classes that actually inherit from `ImplAdd` define constant values and a unique value type for those constants, much like a scoped enum.

```
//by using true as the template argument, the operators + and += will be defined
class MyEnum : public ImplAdd<MyEnum, true>{
    int get_val_() const override{
        return (int)value;
    }
    void set_val_(int v) override{
        value = (ValueT)v;
    }
public:
    enum class ValueT{
        zero, one, two
    };
private:
    typedef  int UnderlyingT;
    ValueT value;
public:
    static const ValueT zero = ValueT::zero;
    static const ValueT one = ValueT::one;
    static const ValueT two = ValueT::two;
    MyEnum(ValueT x) : value(x){}
    MyEnum(const MyEnum& other) : value(other.value){}
};
```

From my perspective, the following code should now easily compile, but it doesn't.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyEnum my = MyEnum::zero;                //works
    my += MyEnum::one;                       //works
    my = MyEnum(MyEnum::zero) + MyEnum::two; //works
    my = MyEnum::zero + MyEnum(MyEnum::two); //ERROR C2676
    my = MyEnum::zero + MyEnum::two;         //ERROR C2676
    MyEnum my2 = my + my;                    //works
    return 0;
}
```

For both lines marked with C2676, the following error message is printed:

```
error C2676: binary '+' : 'const MyEnum::ValueT' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the use of defining an operator as an in-class friend the common way to enable implicit conversion on both arguments? If not, how can I do it in this case?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27281500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§13.3.1.2 [over.match.oper]/p3 (emphasis added):

> for a binary operator `@` with a left operand of a type whose
>   cv-unqualified version is `T1` and a right operand of a type whose
>   cv-unqualified version is `T2`, three sets of candidate functions,
>   designated *member candidates*, *nonmember candidates* and *built-in
>   candidates*, are constructed as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of `operator@` in the context of the expression according to
>     the usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2)
>     except that all member functions are ignored. **However, if no operand
>     has a class type, only those non-member functions in the lookup set
>     that have a first parameter of type `T1` or “reference to (possibly
>     cv-qualified) T1”, when `T1` is an enumeration type, or (if there is a
>     right operand) a second parameter of type `T2` or “reference to
>     (possibly cv-qualified) `T2`”, when `T2` is an enumeration type, are
>     candidate functions.**
> - [...]

In plainer English, if neither operand has a class type, then you need to have an exact match on an enumeration operand for the overload to be considered, which is why `my = MyEnum::zero + MyEnum::two;` does not work. `my = MyEnum::zero + MyEnum(MyEnum::two);`, oddly enough, compiles in GCC but not Clang. I can't find anything that makes it not legal, so I'm suspecting that this might be a compiler bug.

Comment: While this is certainly the right answer to the question why this doesn't work, do you have any idea what a possible solution might be?